# SQLについてご教授お願いします

Tags: c#, sql, linq

お世話になってます。

IDと日付と連番が同じでコードが1234と1235のデータを取得したいと考えています。

tableA
    ID　  日付　　　　連番　　コード
    1    20060223     1     1234
    1    20060223     1     1235

```
1    20060415     1     1111

1    20060415     3     1234
1    20060415     3     1235

1    20060415     3     1111



2    20060415     1     5555

2    20060415     1     1234
3    20060415     1     1235

4    20060415     2     1235
4    20060415     3     1235

4    20060417     1     1234
4    20060417     1     1235

6    20060415     1     1111

6    20060415     1     1234
6    20060415     1     1235

6    20060415     1     2345
6    20060415     1     5555

期待値

1    20060223     1     1234
1    20060223     1     1235

1    20060415     3     1234
1    20060415     3     1235

4    20060417     1     1234
4    20060417     1     1235

6    20060415     1     1234
6    20060415     1     1235
```

環境
sql server 2008 R2
linqでの取得方法も併せてご教授いただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

まず*IDと日付と連番が同じ*という条件があるので、これらの項目でグループ化する必要があります。
各グループが条件を満たしているかどうかの判定はこの場合`WHERE コード IN ('1234', '1235')`とコードを制限した後、各グループの件数を`COUNT(DISTINCT コード)`で確認して2種類のコードが取得されていればいいのではないかと思います。
ですのでグループのキーを取得するSQLは以下のようになります。

```
SELECT ID, 日付, 連番
  FROM tableA
 WHERE コード IN ('1234', '1235')
 GROUP BY ID, 日付, 連番
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT コード) = 2
```

このSELECT文を副問い合わせに使用して`JOIN`や`IN`、`EXISTS`と組み合わせれば目的のSQLを実現することができます。
例えば`INNER JOIN`を使用した場合は

```
SELECT *
  FROM tableA t
 INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, 日付, 連番
      FROM tableA
     WHERE コード IN ('1234', '1235')
     GROUP BY ID, 日付, 連番
     HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT コード) = 2
) k ON t.ID = k.ID AND t.日付 = k.日付 AND t.連番 = k.連番
 WHERE コード IN ('1234', '1235')
```

のようになります。
LINQでの実装も同じ方針で実現可能です。

Comment: @pgrhoさん　回答ありがとうございます。今自分の環境に合わせて抽出しているところです。また何かありましたらよろしくお願いします。